# Who initialize the flash?

Tags: linux, arm, u-boot, flash-memory

I am learning about Linux boot process on ARM processors and find that U-boot is boot from the flash and then u-boot code intialize the RAM to set up the execution environment like stack set up and all
and relocate itself.

Now my question who initialize the flash so that u-boot code can execute?

Also is it any difference booting it from NOR flash or NAND flash?

Is booting from NOR flash is faster than booting from NAND flash?

Comment: I would not close this as *off-topic*, however it is *too broad*.  Specific chips have mechanisms to do this. The lowest common denominator is to solder them already programmed.  However, that went out of favour about 10+ years ago. Really it depends on the chip.

Comment: *"I am learning about Linux boot process on ARM processors and find that ..."* -- You are describing just one of many boot schemes used by ARM processors.  There are ARM systems that load U-Boot into SDRAM, and U-Boot never relocates itself.  Such systems (e.g. Atmel SAM9) may have as many as three stages of bootloaders before Linux (or whatever OS) is loaded.

Comment: I was re-reading the question and agree with sawdust there are many schemes and bootloaders.  I think we may agree with the various steps involved like preparing the ram if you have dram then it may need to be brought up and should be brought up before linux, but that doesnt mean you have to do it in uboot.  Before device trees, booting linux was quite trivial and there is absolutely no reason for something as complicated and big as uboot in order to boot linux, our solution, with or without device trees is to not require a uboot type of loader, we can boot without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

naturally someone has to program that flash the first time.  And each board design determines how that actually happens, sometimes the part is programmed before being soldered down, sometimes there is a backdoor a connector you can program through, etc.  Sometimes not.  Sometimes the processor or other hardware on the board has some other kind of bootloader that you can use to program that normal boot flash, etc.

NOR or NAND isnt usually much of a difference, my biggest problem with the newer flashes is worrying about read-disturb.  Flash reading is faster than writing and a lot of the effort is or at least needs to be in write speed and density and cost, so I would assume that is where the efforts are and not so much read speed vs write speed.  If you have a read speed problem, then just copy the bootloader to ram as soon as you can and run from there, stay off the prom after that.

Comment: Thanks @dwelch for responding to it,is it like once we power on the board ,flash is all ready to be used and communication between processor and flash happens through address and data bus,also I though cells placement in NOR flash makes it better choice for booting the u-boot.Is not it the case?

Comment: I have boards with nand base and with nor based and they both just work and I dont (yet) have a reason to care about one from another.  it depends on the design of the chip and the board as to how the interface works, yes to be able to boot off of it the chip and board have to be designed so that it just powers up and works.  Once you get past the chicken and egg problem of getting that flash programmed the first time (with non-buggy code, code that doesnt crash).

Comment: At my day job we work with the board engineers on every board to make sure the flash is how we want and that a bricked board does not require a soldering iron.  I have not taken the time to see how the ti and marvell and calvium and other uboot capable chips work and how the beagles and open-rd and panda and other boards are setup, much less what the recovery process is if you trash that flash or otherwise brick the board.

Comment: I thought just because NAND is cheaper ,most of board design go for it and in fact this is something has been asked to my friend in an job interview.

Comment: fair enough, another answer may be that depending on the interface you look at what parts are available with that interface at the size you want and speed and lead time and cost.  If after that sort you have a NAND/NOR choice then make it...

Comment: The primary boot loader on most ARM SoC parts is in fact in mask PROM in the device - which usually allows with the flash having been programmed using some other interface.

In saying that, the two techniques commonly used in bulk electronics manufacture are either to use a contractor to program and then tape-and-reel the flash devices ready for placement or to use JTAG to in-circuit program.   The former is rather predicated to larger volumes, and the latter probably slower.

Comment: I would disagree with that statement for the types of processors we are talking about.  arm based microcontrollers, sure I would agree with that, but that is not what we are talking about here.